# How can put the value into the list?

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python. I have a list as below.

```
1    [2,3,4]    10    
2    [3,4]      20    
3    [4]        30
```

Then, I want to make the 2nd column above of elements become the 1st column below and calculate the 2nd column below by the last column above divided by the total elements in the 2nd column as below.

```
2    10/3    
3    10/3    
4    10/3    
3    20/2    
4    20/2      
4    30/1
```

Comment: Your data is not a list, what is it really? csv with a list in 2nd column?

Comment: it is not a csv. I did some process and make this list. and now i need to get the below list.

Comment: Is it `[1, [2, 3, 4], 10]`, etc?

Comment: yes, it is [1,[2,3,4],10] and over 10k rows. So, i think i need to iterate it

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to reformat your data into a bit more usable format. I'll include some extra steps so it makes more sense as to how it all works together.

```
input_list = [] ### initializes the list you'll be using (otherwise you have no list to add to)

row_1 = [1,[2,3,4], 10]
row_2 = [2,[3,4], 20]
row_3 = [3,[4], 30]

input_list.append(row_1)
input_list.append(row_2)
input_list.append(row_3)
```

This will result in all your data being assigned to `input_list` like so,

```
input_list = [[1,[2,3,4], 10], [2,[3,4], 20], [3,[4], 30]]
```

which can now be used to iterate through to get the answers you are looking. You can of course, skip defining each row as it's own variable and then appending each to `input_list` by just defining `input_list` with all of your data in one step. But for the sake of readability and understanding everything that's going on, I used the step by step approach above. Now by creating a function with the `input_list` as a parameter, you can create two simple loops (one within the other) to do what you need,

```
def operation(input):
    output = []  ### initializes your final output list variable
    for row in input:
        for number in row[1]:
            column1 = row[0]
            column2 = number
            column3 = row[2]/len(row[1])
            output.append([column1, column2, column3])
    return output
```

And then to actually create the output you need, call the `operation` function with `input_list` as the parameter,

```
output_list = operation(input_list)
```

where `output_list` is a newly defined variable that will be assigned to whatever the `operation` function returns (your output).

To then see the list in a readable format, run this as well,

```
for row in output_list:
    print row
```

This should give you what you are looking for!

Comment: the input of row_1 should be [1,[2,3,4],10], how to manage it?

Comment: I've edited above to take care of this. Should take care of adding the row number as the first entry of each list